# Error in Google Calendar API PHP when creating new event

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-calendar-api

I have an error showing up when i run this script. All my id's and such are set. The code also comes to the point of `if($client->getAccessToken())`. I want to insert an event into my calendar but this is not working like expected. I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Google_Service_Calendar_Event::toSimpleObject() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mva/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Resource.php:108 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mva/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/Calendar/Resource/Events.php(126): Google_Service_Resource->call('insert', Array, 'Google_Service_...') #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mva/controllers/google.php(56): Google_Service_Calendar_Resource_Events->insert('primary', Object(Google_Service_Calendar_Event)) #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mva/libs/Bootstrap.php(53): Google->index() #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mva/index.php(17): Bootstrap->__construct() #4 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mva/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Resource.php on line 108

Here is my code. Do you guys have any idea what i'm doing wrong? If you have questions just ask them. Thanks!

```
Session::init();    
include('GoogleClient/Collection.php');
include('GoogleClient/Exception.php');
include('GoogleClient/Client.php');
include('GoogleClient/Service.php');
include('GoogleClient/autoload.php');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('doesntmatter-whateveryouwant');
$client->setClientId('xxxxxxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/mva/index');
$client->setDeveloperKey('xxxxxxxxx');
$cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}


if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  echo "<hr><font size=+1>I have access to your calendar</font>";
  $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
  $event->setSummary('Halloween');
  $event->setLocation('The Neighbourhood');
  $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
  $start->setDateTime('2018-03-29T10:00:00.000-05:00');
  $event->setStart($start);
  $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
  $end->setDateTime('2018-03-29T10:25:00.000-05:00');
  $event->setEnd($end);
  $calendarId = 'primary';
  $events = $cal->events->insert('primary', $event);
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else {
      $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
      print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
    }
            $this->view->render('google/index');   

}
```

**EDIT** i know for a fact that my the error shows up at this line:

```
$events = $cal->events->insert('primary', $event);
```

But i'm doing it exactly as the [docs](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Calendar_Events_Resource.html) telling me to.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious as to why you are setting the access token after you make the insert call wouldn't you want to do that before?  The following example is directly from the documentation.

[Events.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
    array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
```

Comment: That is the strange thing. Because if i copy and paste this code i get the exact same error as above... Something tells me that Google has updated the code yet again or something.

Comment: And the script that comes within the `vendor` is trying to load a method that isn't even within that class...

Comment: try installing the library again with composer sounds like something went wrong.   you should just be doing require_once '/path/to/your-project/vendor/autoload.php';  https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php